# How do I set up scanning from an HP OfficeJet Pro on NixOS?

Tags: nixos, scanner

I have cups printing working on `NixOS` with my HP OfficeJet Pro 8610.
But how do I get scanning working with, say, `simple-scan`?

Answer (score 2):

So it's pretty simple, actually; in your `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`, add the following:

```
hardware.sane = {
  enable = true;
  extraBackends = [ pkgs.hplipWithPlugin ];
};
```

And for user(s) that you want to allow to scan, add them to the "scanner" group:

```
users.users.<username>.extraGroups = [ ... "scanner" ];
```

(edited)

Comment: Thanks for this solution. At the end of the first code block, there is one semicolon missing.

Comment: Good point; corrected.  Thanks!